# Register model changes to MDL input elements

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design-lite

When integrating MDL with a framework, the framework will set the values for inputs directly, but the changes won't get noticed by the MDL libraries, as those are likely bound to click and change events. For example, if I have:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="joke" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="joke">Joke...</label>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a number!</span>
</div>
```

but then change the value with some javascript:

```
document.getElementById('joke').value=text;
```

the element label does not move, and is covered by the text. In short, the `is-dirty` class is not set.

Here is an example that shows the issue in more detail. https://plnkr.co/6pAh7ApQT8TUUS9G9QBg

I am currently working on a project in Angular2, but I think the overall issue is framework agnostic. I'm hoping some better solutions than my 'answer'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found for this is to use a directive. You can call checkDirty() on the element.

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, AfterViewChecked} from '@angular/core';
declare var componentHandler: any;

@Directive({
    selector: '[mdl]'
})
export class MDL implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        let mdlField = this.element.nativeElement.MaterialTextfield;
        if (mdlField) {
            mdlField.checkDirty();
            mdlField.checkValidity();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your template simply include this directive in the parent div of the mdl input

```
<div mdl class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--5-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="promoCode_{{inRibbon}}">Promo code</label>
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="promoCode" name="promoCode_{{inRibbon}}" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="itemAvailabilityRequest.promoCode">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

binding to the class list, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass, might be a better way:

example:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-text-field--floating-label"
    [class.is-dirty]=" val != null && val != '' ">
```

or for mdl-tabs:

```
<div class="mdl-tabs__panel"
    [class.is-active]="val_is_active_tab">
```

or for mdl-checkboxes:

```
<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect"
      [class.is-checked]="val == 1">
```

Original answer:

For my project my temp solution was to put in some very un-angular2 code:

```
private thingsToDirty = [];
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    for (let id of this.thingsToDirty) {
        let el: any = document.getElementById(id);
        if (el != undefined && 
        el.parentNode.className.indexOf("is-dirty") == -1) {
            el.parentNode.className += " is-dirty";
        }
    }
    this.thingsToDirty.length = 0;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.something.getJSONfromServer().subscribe( data => {
        this.thing = data;
        this.thingsToDirty.push('thing_id');
    });
}
```